# Application Controller Loop Methods alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails app in which i need to be doing some actions each time a page refresh happens (it may even use ajax later to do it in a timed manner as well). My database contains entries that expire based on their timestamps. Therefore, my checking mechanism on each refresh goes about checking whether the entries have expired and performing appropriate actions.

Notice that this is all part of the Rails app. It does not have to do with cron or external apps. Currently, i am doing this on my application controller. I have a module that i include in my application controller and it pretty much performs all the "loop" methods i want to perform.

I am wondering whether there's a gem or a more concise method of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/

Create a Job that clears the entries.

Run some workers.

From your controllers, whenever an action hit (page refresh) occur, enqueue the cleaning Job.

There is an external dependency, Redis, but all the mechanics runs under the Rails hood.

It is performant, scales well, don't stinks nor has fleas like cron...

Comment: Well, i've heard of the gem before, but it feels more like a background processor to me. The actions i want to do are based on the application logic itself per session, are more like keeping state after some time has passed. In particular, in this case, it's actually a game loop, where depending on the timestamp of entries upon refresh, new actions are generated or entries are updating. I don't really need a thread though to catch up with those. It's user based and changes for each user.

Comment: If it is for a game, then I would suggest Redis more than before, seriously, it can also do PubSub, and is simpler to maintain than RabbitMQ. It is definately not only a background processor. If it is user based, than simply enqueue the jobs with the proper user id, than, the job, clears only the relevant records...